# OIDs for HmacSHA512/224 and HmacSHA512/256?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, hmac, sha512

The [NIST Cryptographic Algorithm Object Registration page](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/crypto_apps_infra/csor/algorithms.html) lists OIDs for SHA-512/224 and SHA-512/256 but not for the HMAC algorithms based on them. Are they defined somewhere else? I understand they are used in HMAC_DRBG as described in [NIST SP 800-90A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited to [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) and doesn't contain a programming question.

Comment: Oops, for SHA512, I don't know those out of the top of my head... just a moment... and I didn't find it. Not very much used anyway.

Comment: The internal state of HMAC_DRBG depends strongly on the output of the hash. It would be a rather big shame if you would use SHA-512 and then toss away half or more than half of the bits.

Comment: You could use HMAC-SHA512 and then use the 256 or 224 leftmost bits. That would be more secure than using the 64 bit optimized versions with an output size of 256 or 224 for the hash itself. It would be non-standard, but you won't find many HMAC's based on the 64 bit optimized versions of SHA-2 with an output size of 256 or 224 either.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I personally don't have a preference for them. I just need a list of OIDs for all supported algorithms that users can choose from.

Comment: Simply leave these ones out then. I've never heard of them being used for this purpose (most people wouldn't even know they exist)